# Mac can't open system vim in terminal

Tags: macos, bash, vim

I tried to upgrade my system Vim from 7.3 to a high version so I used macport to do that. This newer version is located in `/opt/local/bin/`. Later I decided to uninstall it due to some reason.

Now I can't open my system Vim in the terminal, the error message is `-bash: /opt/local/bin/vim: No such file or directory`. Somehow the machine still thinks the vim is located in `/opt/local/bin/`.

Then weird thing happens, when I type `which vim`, it shows my vim located at `/usr/local/bin`, and there is indeed a vim folder in that directory, but I can't open it by typing `vim` in the terminal.

So here is the situation: I have two working versions of Vim in my machine, a 7.3 version in `/usr/bin` and a 7.4 version in `/usr/local/bin`(I don't know how I got this one). Both working (I have to type the whole directory `/urs/bin/vim` or `/urs/local/bin/vim`), but can't be opened in the terminal by simply typing `vim`.

#### Updates:

now I can use `vi` or `vim`, but the problem is, the former opens 7.3 whereas the latter opens 7.4

Comment: `hash -r vim`, then try again.  Or create a new window.  Bash remembered where `vim` was found, and expects to find it there again.  When you removed `vim`, it got upset (rather than try to find it again).

Comment: In my machine, the path priority from high to low is: `opt/local/bin/`, 'usr/local/bin/`, 'usr/bin`. So I think this explains the behaviour of `which vim`. But why simply typing`vim` doesn't work?

Comment: It works, but now `vi` opens the 7.3 version and `vim` opens the 7.4 version.

Comment: That depends on where there are links called `vi`.  Presumably, there is no `vi` in `/usr/local/bin`, so it falls back on the `vi` in `/usr/bin` which is a link to `/usr/bin/vim`.  You can either decide you like this, or create a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` too: `ln -s vim /usr/local/bin/vi` (you may need `sudo` / admin privileges to do that).

Comment: Is there any way to make `vi` and `vim` open the same version just like it used to? Maybe replace the 7.3 version in `usr/bin` with the 7.4 one or create some link?

Comment: My previous comment told you how to do it. You'd need to use `hash -r` again, of course.

Answer (score 2):

At the current command window, type:

```
$ hash -r
```

then try running `vim` again.  Or create a new window and try in that.

Bash remembered where `vim` was found, and expects to find it there again.  When you removed `vim`, it got upset and complained (rather than try to find it again before complaining).  Using `hash -r vim` forgets all previously hashed commands and then finds `vim` explicitly.  Run `hash` with no options to see what it knows.

See the Bash manual on [`hash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-hash) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The default Vim is `/usr/bin/vim`. There is absolutely no reason whatsoever to change it.

If you want a more up-to-date Vim, install MacVim and use the bundled `mvim` script instead of `vim`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, at first I was unwilling to use MacVim. One more question, do you know how to uninstall the 7.4 version of Vim that is in `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: That's it? Okay, I'll give it a try. Thanks